# Linq Join Duplicates records c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am having a problem and I would be grateful if anyone could help. I have 3 lists from 3 db tables. Accounts, contact and contact details. The issue is when I try to add to 2 extra fields to my query it duplicates records for example result should contain 700 rows in the list but if I add contact.firstname and contact.lastname the results are 8000.

Each Account can have many contacts,
Each contact have many contactdetails

```
var Dataset = (from account in ctx.Accounts
from contact in ctx.Contacts
from contactdetails in ctx.ContactDetails.Where(x => x.id == account.id || x.id == 
account.contactdetailsid)

select new { account.id, account.Reference, account.AccountName, contactdetails.Title, 
account.Balance }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I cant seem figure out why adding contact.firstname and contact.lastname is causing duplicates records when i change to below: Results go from 700 to 8000.

```
select new { account.id, account.Reference, account.AccountName, contactdetails.Title, 
account.Balance, contact.firstname , contact.lastname }).Distinct().ToList();
```

This does not give the correct results

Comment: [Read this first](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions. You should split them into two actual questions. Focus on the correctness, then worry about the performance. Be sure to post a good code example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You appear to have taken the question out of your question.

Comment: .Where(x => x.id == account.id || x.id == 
account.contactdetailsid) => Interesting condition...

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it. I am trying to see if there is something I am missing in the way I have wrote this query. Its works perfectly with when I do not add  contact.firstname and contact.lastname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing an outer join with accounts, contacts and contact details. So for every Account, for every Contact, for every ContactDetail that matches your criteria, you'll end up with an entry in the result set. Someone tried to get around this by throwing a `.Distinct()` on the result set, which happened to filter the results down a bit. But as soon as you add properties from the `contact`, you end up with a bunch of different first and last names for each object that the query was returning before.

You probably meant to do something like this:

```
var Dataset = (from account in ctx.Accounts
from contact in account.Contacts
from contactdetails in contact.ContactDetails
select new { account.id, account.Reference, account.AccountName, contactdetails.Title, 
    account.Balance, contact.firstname , contact.lastname })
.ToList();
```

### Update

If you don't have navigation properties, you can achieve the same results using `join`s or `where` clauses:

```
var Dataset = (from account in ctx.Accounts
    join contact in ctx.Contacts 
        on account.id equals contact.accountid
    join contactdetails in ctx.ContactDetails 
        on contact.contactdetailsid equals contactdetails.id
    select new { account.id, account.Reference, account.AccountName, contactdetails.Title, 
        account.Balance, contact.firstname , contact.lastname })
.ToList();
```

... or ...

```
var Dataset = (from account in ctx.Accounts
    from contact in ctx.Contacts 
    where account.id == contact.accountid
    from contactdetails in ctx.ContactDetails 
    where contact.contactdetailsid == contactdetails.id
    select new { account.id, account.Reference, account.AccountName, contactdetails.Title, 
        account.Balance, contact.firstname , contact.lastname })
.ToList();
```

Either of these approaches should produce exactly the same execution plan, but the `join` clauses represent your intent better from a semantic standpoint.

Comment: So, in other words, the Where condition doesn't check for a match of the contact or contactdetails, only for a match with account via account.id or account.contactdetailsid (please correct me if I'm wrong, StriplingWarrior - my Linq is quite rusty).

@Jimbo Jones, could you provide a sample of your results so we can give you more help?

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is create one list from 3 lists. So for each account have Account name, Account Reference, Account balance, contacts first and last name and finally contact details title. With your sample code i get the following: Account' does not contain a definition for 'Contacts' and no extension method 'Contacts' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: @JimboJones: I don't know what provider you're using, but you should check your configuration to see why you're not getting navigation properties. You *can* get around this by crafting a `where` statement that makes sure all the appropriate IDs align, but it's a lot simpler if you can use navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks StriplingWarrior for all your help.

Comment: @JimboJones: No problem. I added an update that you might be interested in. Basically the same thing you did, but with syntax that you might find more pleasing.

Answer (score 0):

From StriplingWarrior post it helped me find a working solution.

```
   var Dataset = (
   from account in ctx.Accounts
   from contact in ctx.Contacts.Where(x => x.accountid == account.id)
   from contactdetails in ctx.ContactDetails.Where(x =>  x.id == contact.contactdetailsid)

                              select new {
                                   AccountID    = account.id,
                                   Reference    = account.Reference,
                                   AccountName  = account.AccountName,
                                   External     = contact == null ? String.Empty : (contact.External),
                                   Phone        = contactdetails == null ? String.Empty : (contactdetails.Title),
                                   Balance      = account.Balance,
                                   ContactName  = contact == null ? String.Empty : (contact.firstname + " " + contact.lastname),                            
                               }).ToList();
```