# Duplicate Output with Entity Framework and LINQ and Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

## Overview

I have a website I am writing for keeping personal bookmarks.  And they are kept in categories.  I can print out the links just fine when doing it one way.  But when I throw a linq query in the mix, somehow I get duplicates of each link.

## Scenarios

### First way without duplicates

Now I removed the html code from the loops because it is unimportant.

```
var categoryContext = new LinkDatabaseEntities();
var linkContext = new LinkDatabaseEntities();
foreach (Category category in categoryContext.Categories)
{
    foreach (Link link in linkContext.Links)
    {
        if (link.CatID.Equals(category.ID))
        {
            Print Out HTML Code
        }
   }
}
```

This code works perfectly.  I don't get any duplicates.

**Output:**

- Category 1

  - Link 1
  - Link 2
- Category 2

  - Link 1
  - Link 2

### Code that outputs duplicates

Now, the information in the database isn't going to be that big, so I really don't need this for efficiency, I just want to understand what is happening.

```
var categoryContext = new LinkDatabaseEntities();
var linkContext = new LinkDatabaseEntities();
foreach (Category category in categoryContext.Categories)
{
    var links = from link in linkContext.Links
                where link.catID == category.ID
                select link;

    foreach (Link link in links)
    {
        Print Out HTML Code
    }
}
```

This way has duplicates of every link.  I don't understand why this is happening.

### Output:

- Category 1

  - Link 1
  - Link 1
  - Link 2
  - Link 2
- Category 2

  - Link 1
  - Link 1
  - Link 2
  - Link 2

---

If someone could explain why this is happening, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: Re 2nd code listing - pretty sure that is expected behaviour because it takes all of A and muliplies it by all the items in B thus A x B = All-of-the-items-in-A-duplicated-by-the-count-of-items-in-B.  I think you need to add a `Distinct` in there somewhere.  Or maybe a join.

Comment: I fixed the capitalization issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP:

> This way has duplicates of every link. I don't understand why this is happening.

It's happening because you did not use a `join`, if you don't it mulitplies out the items in A by the count of items in B.  A similar issue and solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683289/linq-join-duplicates-records-c-sharp).

### Navigation properties

---

This assumes you have correctly defined relationships and foreign keys in your database schema and have corresponding information in your EF code/EDMX.

---

Considering you are using an ORM, an easier way that doesn't lead to duplicates is to take advantage of the EF Navigation Properties.

Change the following:

```
var categoryContext = new LinkDatabaseEntities();
var linkContext = new LinkDatabaseEntities();
foreach (Category category in categoryContext.Categories)
{
    var links = from link in linkContext.Links
                where link.catID == category.ID
                select link;

    foreach (Link link in links)
    {
        Print Out HTML Code
    }
}
```

...to:

```
var categoryContext = new LinkDatabaseEntities();
var linkContext = new LinkDatabaseEntities();
foreach (var category in categoryContext.Categories)
{
    foreach (var link in category.Links) // <---- notice the use of the nav property
    {
        // the above category.Links contains only the links applicable
        // for a given category AND NOT all the links found in say a LINKS table

        (Print Out HTML Code)
    }
}
```

The above works by taking advantage that EF already knows which `Link`s belong to a given `Category` because the navigation properties reflect the relationships and foreign keys defined in the database schema.

### See also

- *[Relationships, navigation properties, and foreign keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships)*, Learn, Microsoft, retrieved 2022-12-4